# How to undestand relations between types any, unknown, {} and between them and other types?

Tags: typescript, types

Trying to understand relations between types I have this code

```
type CheckIfExtends<A, B> = A extends B ? true : false;

type T1 = CheckIfExtends<number, unknown>; //true
type T2 = CheckIfExtends<number, {}>; //true
type T3 = CheckIfExtends<number, any>; //true
type T4 = CheckIfExtends<() => void, unknown>; //true
type T5 = CheckIfExtends<() => void, {}>; //true
type T6 = CheckIfExtends<() => void, any>; //true
type T7 = CheckIfExtends<unknown, any>; //true
type T8 = CheckIfExtends<any, unknown>; //true
type T9 = CheckIfExtends<{}, unknown>; //true
type T10 = CheckIfExtends<{}, any>; //true
type T11 = CheckIfExtends<any, {}>; //boolean
type T12 = CheckIfExtends<unknown, {}>; //false
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=48&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFhAxgawJIDMCiAPYEB2AJgM4A8AggDRQBCAfFALxTlQS4Em1QD8UwAJwCu0AFxR0AQwA2xCAG4AUItCQoAFQCMTWAhQYceImXxCAtgCMIA6kPzJ8AewDu+OvKgB6T4JErw0OoATDrwSGhYHMakppbW1ADeAL7uXj7CEP5q6gDMoXoRhpwm5lY2UJL4IKnevpmqgQAs+eEGUSSkABQAlEwMAG6OAJaEtvZOrjXpfg0aAKwt+pFGHT19UIMjiSketRlZgQBsi4XtZGuMA8OjFVVTdQcaAOwnbStkdg4u+NSV1bvTeoBDQADley2KpD+Yy+kwBD1m6gAnOCitFkjCJm54ftEZoAAyos6kDG3f5pBHArTaZhhJZojrQqDJKYWRyOaQQSqPLQhWkFN6Qz5Y7ZTKSyTJAA)

Could someone explain this? What difference? How is it possible that `any extends {}` and `any` does not extend `{}` at the same time? If `any extends unknown` and `unknown extends any` then does it mean they are strongly equal? Is it a new flaw of Typescript on top of `null` and `undefinded` equity issue of JavaScript?

Actually,

```
type T = CheckIfExtends<any, number>; //boolean
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The distinction is essentially this:

- [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) is deliberately unsound, in that it is assignable both *to and from*  any other type (with the possible exception of `never`, depending on where you're using it).  Unsoundness means that some basic rules for types are broken, such as [transitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) of [subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping).   Generally, if `A` is assignable to `B`, and `B` is assignable to `C`, then `A` is assignable to `C`.  But `any` breaks this.  For example: `string` is assignable to `any`, and `any` is assignable to `number`... but `string` is *not* assignable to `number`.  This particular unsoundness is very useful, because it allows us to essentially "turn off" type checking in a part of code which is either hard or impossible to type correctly.  But you need to be very careful thinking of `any` as a type; it's more of an "un-type".
- [the empty type, `{}`,](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces) is a type that can be treated like an object at runtime (that is, something you can read properties or methods from without a runtime error), but it has no *known* properties at compile time.  That doesn't mean it has no properties; it just means that the compiler doesn't know about any of them.  This implies that only `null` and `undefined` are not assignable to `{}` (`null.foo` or `undefined.foo` are runtime errors).  Even primitive types like `string` can be treated as having properties and methods at runtime (`"".length` and `"".toUpperCase()` work, and even `"".foo` just returns `undefined`).  And of course any actual object type will also be assignale to `{}`.

  On the other hand, the `{}` type is not assignable *to* very many types.  If I have  value of type `{}` as try to assign it to a variable of type `{foo: string}`, there will be a compiler error, as `{}` is not known to contain a `foo` property.  You can assign `{}` to itself, or to a wider type like `unknown`, or to the "un-type" `any`.

  This makes `{}` very *nearly* [a top type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_type), which is a type to which all other types are assignable.  It's essentially a top type with `null` and `undefined` removed from it.
- [the `unknown` type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) was introduced in TypeScript 3.0 and is the *true* top type; every type in TypeScript is assignable to `unknown`.  Even `null` and `undefined` are assignable to `unknown`.

  Again, on the other hand, `unknown` is only assignable to itself and the "un-type" `any`.  Even the `{}` type isn't wide enough for you to assign `unknown` to it.  Instead, `unknown` is essentially equivalent to `{} | null | undefined` (and is seen as such since [TypeScript 4.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-8.html#improved-intersection-reduction-union-compatibility-and-narrowing))

---

Most of your `CheckIfExtends<A, B>` results can be explained by the above.  The exception is `T11`:

```
type T11 = CheckIfExtends<any, {}>; //boolean
```

Your `CheckIfExtends<A, B>` type definition is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types), which does some interesting things when `A` is a union type, in that it allows both branches of the conditional to be taken if the pieces of the union satisfy both branches.  It also does the same distribution when `A` is `any`, except when `B` is `any` or `unknown` (so `T8` behaves normaly).  There's some discussion of this in [microsoft/TypeScript#27418](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27418).  Anyway, `T11` takes both branches and you get `true | false` which is `boolean`.  (From microsoft/TypeScript#27418, `unknown` in the `A` position does not distribute, so `T7` and `T12` behave normally as well).

Answer (score 2):

I will start from what means `extends` in TypeScript. On the first look on it, it behaves strange, as for product types (like objects) behaves like *'is superset'* and for `unions` as *'is subset'*, also totally differently it works for function types. It can look strange at first, but it is logical behavior, in other words most types have [soundness property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness).

My rule of thumb to understand this concept is to **read `extends` as `assignable to`**. Then if `x` extends `y`, it means that `x` can be used whenever `y` is required.

Lets consider three different algebraic data types, if for them above holds true.

**For product type**

```
type A = {a: string}
type B = {a: string; b: number}
type BextendsA = B extends A ? true : false // evaluates to true
```

Above is true because B can be used in every places where A is required, as B covers the whole structure A has. B is a superset of A. But what holds here is B is assignable to A.

**For union type**

```
type A = number | string
type B = number
type BextendsA = B extends A ? true : false // evaluates to true
```

Totally differently it looks for union. B for product was a superset, for union B is a subset! Yes, different logic, B does not represent all values possible in A, but whenever A is required B can be used instead. So B is assignable to A.

**For function types**

```
type A = (a: number) => void
type B = () => void
type BextendsA = B extends A ? true : false // evaluates to true
```

For function types, it looks even more weird as A looks like more specified function then B, so how B can extends A then? This goes from the assignability again, as whenever something needs A, we can assign B. This is very visible in example like `Array.map`. Consider:

```
[1,2].map(x => x + 1)
```

Array.map requires function which has three arguments - `(el,index,arr) => any` but can work with a function which has only one argument `el => any`. And again it holds the assignability, B is assignable to A.

---

Types like `any`, `unknown`, `{}` are unsound, it means that their behavior cannot be proven logically. Understanding how they behave in TS is more just understanding the specification and reasons about such decisions. But it cannot be logically explained, as unsound type behave against logic.

> The places where TypeScript allows unsound behavior were carefully considered, and throughout this document we’ll explain where these happen and the motivating scenarios behind them.