# TypeScript claims no error even if parameter has the wrong type

Tags: javascript, typescript, return-type, tsc

I have a function that takes a dictionary as the first argument. This dictionary has string as keys, and functions as values. The problem is that, if a function in the dictionary has a bad signature, TypeScript does not complain!

A piece of code is worth 1000 words. Here's my `main.ts`:

```
interface MyMap {
    [key: string]: (x: number) => void;
}

function f(map: MyMap, key: string, x: number) : void{
    map.hasOwnProperty(key) ? map[key](x) : console.log(x)
}

const stupidMap: MyMap = {
    'square': (x) => {
        console.log(x*x);

        return x*x; // This function should return void!!
    },
    'double': (x) => {
        console.log(x+x);
    }
}

f(stupidMap, 'square', 5) // Prints 25
f(stupidMap, 'double', 5) // Prints 10
```

I compile it with `tsc main.ts`, and I get no error whatsoever. `tsc --version` prints `Version 3.7.2`. I have two questions:

1. **Why don't I get any error?**
2. **Am I missing some compile flags that would cause this error to show up?**

Any insight would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no issue because `(x: number) => void` is assignable to `(x: number) => number`. And here is a prove of that:

```
type F = (x: number) => void
type Z = (x: number) => number

type ZextendsF = Z extends F ? true : false // evaluate to true
```

And this fact is totally fine for the program flow. If your interface says - I require a function which does not return, then If I pass a function which return something, its fully ok, as I will never use this return data. It is type safe and nothing to worry about.

More details about functions assignability - [Comparing two functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions). Also more details about TypeScript types behavior and relation - [types assignability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59135229/how-to-undestand-relations-between-types-any-unknown-and-between-them-and-o/59140191#59140191).

Comment: Amazing, this explains a lot. However,`function g(): void {return 1;}` still fails. How does it work together with the explanation that "If I pass a function which return something, its fully ok, as I will never use this return data"?

Comment: this is different thing, if you declare function to return `void` then it should return`void`(so have no return). This is not about assignability. You just declare different type then you really are returning. So in this example TS should block you.

Comment: @enanone cause if you type *one* function to *explicitly not return something*, if it returns something that's probably a mistake.

Comment: @enanone these are to different things, first is what you can pass when X is required, and the second is just declaring and fulfilling the interface.

Comment: if you dont assume any return type, then you will not use it, so the program is safe when you pass a function which returns. But when you declare that your function return X, but your function returns really Y, this is a issue which TS should catch.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just for completeness: is there anything I can do so that I get a TypeScript error in the first place? I understand that it is completely fine that I do not get an error --but what if I _really, really_ wanted to get an error? Is it doable somehow?

Comment: The simplest I can think of is just put adhoc type in the implementation - 'square': (x):void ...