# What is the purpose of the empty object type {} in typescript?

Tags: typescript

In the @types/React package of the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) library I ran into this definition

```
interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
        (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement | null;
        propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
        contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
        defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
        displayName?: string;
    }
```

I read that the {} type is called the Empty Object type and its purpose is to describe an object with not properties on its own.

Can someone explain why it's used as a default type for most generic functions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to understand relations between types any, unknown, {} and between them and other types?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59141921/2887218)

Comment: Also see [Breaking Change in TS3.5: Generic type parameters are implicitly constrained to `unknown`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#generic-type-parameters-are-implicitly-constrained-to-unknown)

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain why it's used as a default type for most generic functions ?

It's the default for many react types because if you don't specify what props you want, it's assumed you don't want any. When you don't have any props your component will still receive a props object, that object will just have no properties on it, hence an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

Before TypeScript 3.5, every type that could not be inferred defaulted to `{}`. Since then, it defaults to `unknown`. This is why in a lot of legacy code you will see usage of `{}` instead of `unknown`.

Note that there is a difference between both: `{}` cannot be `null`, while `unknown` can.