# How can I prevent a generic type from taking "any" as its type argument?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, tsconfig

How can I prevent a generic type from taking `any` as its type argument? If my generic argument is constrained by using the `extends` keyword, it feels weird that it can be replaced by `any`.

As far as I understand it, everything extends `any`, but `any` should *not* extend anything (other than `any` itself).

Here's an example:

```
type OneOrTwo = 1 | 2;
type MyType<T extends OneOrTwo> = T;
const t1: MyType<OneOrTwo> = 1; // OK
const t2: MyType<any> = 2;      // OK
const t3: MyType<OneOrTwo> = 3; // Error: Type '3' is not assignable to type 'OneOrTwo';
const t4: MyType<any> = 4;      // OK?? How can I prevent this?
```

Can I have typescript prevent me from typing `t4` like this? Either by changing the code or by using a `tsconfig` option maybe?

Comment: Also strongly related to [How to undestand relations between types any, unknown, {} and between them and other types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59135229/how-to-undestand-relations-between-types-any-unknown-and-between-them-and-o), as the properties you ascribe to `any` are actually correct of `unknown` (that is, everything extends `unknown`, but `unknown` only extends `unknown` itself).

Comment: If you do not think your question is addressed by either of the two above-linked question/answers, please edit it to highlight the differences and the remaining issues.  Otherwise I am inclined to mark this as a duplicate pointing to them.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Yes. The question from your second comment in particular makes it extremely clear that it is by design that this occurs. Thank you!

Comment: Try `type MyType<T extends OneOrTwo> = 0 extends 1 & T ? never : T;` this will prevent any to be set as type

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing you cannot.
Writing `any` anywhere in the code means TypeScript going to do NO checks at all, and this propagates.
You can prevent implicit any in some cases, by setting a combination of the following:

- strict
- noImplicitAny
- stricNullCecks
- noStrictGenericChecks
- strictFunctionTypes
- strictBindCallApply

inside `tsconfig.json`