# Check if function parameter is required or not

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I need the typescript compiler to swear when declaring a function.

Example:

```
function f(r: number, o?: string) {}

type HasRequiredProps<F> = 
    F extends (...args: infer A) => any 
        ? A['length'] extends 1 | 0 
            ? false
            : true
    : false;

type R = HasRequiredProps<typeof f> extends true 
    ? (p: number) => void
    : (p?: number) => void

// Should be an error
const ff: R = function () {
    
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Note that `ff` could have required parameters but you don't actually need to declare them in the function declaration. For example if you add `ff()` in your current example it will error

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68813404/passed-function-without-arguments-doesnt-throw-an-error)?

Comment: @apokryfos I know that if I call the function, there will be an error. But I want to see it at the definition stage.