# How to use negated types in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typing

How can I use a negated or a "not" type in Typescript?

example(just an example), I tried to use `is not` in a type predicate:

```
function notUndef(obj: any): obj is not undefined {
// -------------------------------> ~~~ error!
// cannot find name 'not'.
    return obj !== void(0);
}
```

and

```
function notUndef(obj: any): (typeof obj !== undefined) {
//                   ')' expected -----> ~~~   -----> ~
//                                      ';' expected
    return obj !== void(0);
}
```

but I received errors.

Neither of these work, what can I do?

Comment: What comes after ':' is the return type of the function, you should set it to a specific type

Comment: You should specify return type as bool

Comment: TS doesn’t directly support *negated types*, so there is no “`not`” or the equivalent.  For `not undefined` I would suggest `{} | null` instead, unless you have some specific use case where that doesn’t work?

Comment: People suggesting that you use a return type are possibly unaware of the existence of type predicates?

Comment: It looks like you were trying to use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates). Did you actually look at the docs for that? There is no `not` syntax

Comment: @jcalz yes that do works, but in this case, I need to check only undefined but not null, and if I have my own class, and I want to check object is not my class, | syntax doesn't work

Comment: @Bergi yes I do know there's no 'not' keyword in js or ts, it's just a try

Comment: "I need to check only undefined but not null" Yes, and `{} | null` is the complement of `undefined`.  The only value not assignable to `{} | null` is `undefined`.  I will write up an answer explaining, even though you have already accepted another answer.

Comment: I am going to edit the question to use some more common terminology, which hopefully clears up any of these outstanding downvotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript does not directly support *negated types*, so there's no general way to express "the [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) of `T`". There was an implementation of negated types at [microsoft/TypeScript#29317](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) using the `not` keyword exactly as you are using it in your example.  But this feature was never merged into the language.

There are workarounds which may or may not fit your use case.  In the particular case of `not undefined`, you can write the equivalent type `{} | null`.  The *empty object-like type* `{}` accepts every value except `null` or `undefined` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59141921/2887218) for more info), so the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `{}` with `null` results in  a type that accepts every value except `undefined`:

```
function notUndef(obj: any): obj is {} | null {
    return obj !== void (0);
}

const x = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "abc" : undefined;
if (notUndef(x)) {
    // x: string
    console.log(x.toUpperCase()); // "ABC" if reached
}

const y = ["abc", 123, { a: 456 }, null, undefined][
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];
// const y: string | null | {a: number} | null | undefined
if (notUndef(y)) {
    y // y: string | null | {a: number} | null
} else {
    y // y: undefined
}
```

In general, if the type you'd like to negate can be filtered out of a union type, then you can use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter and [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) to filter the to-be-negated type out of whatever union is passed in.  Here's a way to "negate" an existing [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) (as long as filtering a union works with it):

```
function not<U>(guard: (obj: any) => obj is U) {
    return <T,>(obj: T): obj is Exclude<T, U> => !guard(obj);
}
```

Let's test it with `undefined`:

```
function isUndefined(obj: any): obj is undefined {
    return obj === void (0);
}
const notUndef = not(isUndefined);
// const notUndef: <T>(obj: T) => obj is Exclude<T, undefined>
const x = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "abc" : undefined;
if (notUndef(x)) {
    // x: string
    x.toUpperCase();
}
```

And how about with `number`:

```
function isNumber(obj: any): obj is number {
    return typeof obj === "number";
}
const notNumber = not(isNumber);
// const notNumber: <T>(obj: T) => obj is Exclude<T, number>

const y = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "abc" : 123;
if (notNumber(y)) {
    // y: "abc"
    y.toUpperCase();
} else {
    y.toFixed();
    // y: 123
}
```

So that works.

---

There are limits to these approaches, though.  Some types that cannot be negated trivially.  Imagine you had

```
interface Foo { a: number, b: string }
```

and you wanted to write `not Foo`. You could manually build up a type like:

```
interface Foo { a: number, b: string }
type AllTypes = string | boolean | bigint | null | undefined | symbol | object | number;
type NotFoo =
    Exclude<AllTypes, object> |
    { a?: Exclude<AllTypes, number>, [k: string]: any } |
    { b?: Exclude<AllTypes, string>, [j: string]: any }
```

And I think it works:

```
let nf: NotFoo;
nf = 3;
nf = {};
nf = { a: 2, b: 3, c: 10 } // okay
nf = { a: "", b: "", c: 10 } // okay
nf = { a: 2, b: "", c: 10 } // error
```

but it doesn't scale well.  You could use the generic `Exclude` version, which works well when you pass in a union of known things:

```
function isFoo(obj: any): obj is Foo {
    return obj && typeof obj === "object" &&
        "a" in obj && typeof obj.a === "number" &&
        "b" in obj && typeof obj.b === "string"
}
const notFoo = not(isFoo);
// const notFoo: <T>(obj: T) => obj is Exclude<T, Foo>

const y = [3, {}, {a: 2, b: 3, c: 10}, {a: "", b: "", c: 10}, {a: 2, b: "", c: 10}][
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];
if (notFoo(y)) {
    y 
    // const y: number | 
    // { a?: undefined; b?: undefined; c?: undefined; } | 
    // { a: number; b: number; c: number; } | 
    // { a: string; b: string; c: number; }
} else {
    y // const y: {  a: number; b: string; c: number; }
}
```

but fails when you are passing in a type where you can't just filter out some of the members, such as [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown):

```
const z: unknown = "‍♂️";

if (notFoo(z)) {
    // z: unknown
    z // still unknown
} else {
    // x: never, not Foo 
    z.a // error
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&ssl=23&ssc=24&pln=22&pc=1#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBVYATCAzAwgezBgBsJJgAXJAbwCgakGksBXYecgSz2CWD3LSYsACjwAjAFYAuJCGABPAJQzxEpByjUAvkgA+vZkSLV6jMwCcI5ZuZ6qkAQgC8TpADc8HdEmEAGRQDcpgxadGbw3FCUAB5IrgCyIOQAFgB05nLoBMKKSAA8SL6pAKxIAPxIAEQgYvCVSDKsQhzAEOhBZhxYPnwCGNjC0Yq5tGZmAPTjSNEyUeYtAObBYxHAUHgkqUR4C4Op5HgoMDAQ5jggUBA5gUiTVQCCAEI49V1IlgjJbcuhy6tRSHkcSQAG1qrVKgAaJAARgATABmaFUWQyAAsxQAbEgtNDgIYiNCmtgWm0ALog5ZmRIpVJYbZ4czCGlpDIYbK5ABUSGKijJHUYd3+lHks3I82ACz0BiM0qoIBk+LAYlOOn0+Nl+mJWFJ6GWb2EvUEAyUIypjCBd1FSDmi2lGuM+nliuYytV9oJPyQECIlxMYwttym1u1up+NF+oEgsAQyDQXGAADEOERyKd-YwWGxONxePw8igAHzCBbMEDmdAyUSSGRyJRxQtIewaVBmgMMSzWWz5AAqkOLqhkPeUTck6k0AFFovAiMxMHk+6hG05Gw5S+X0NWJIFw2Ys+wE+PjTrWpvB7IFCPm5pQ6eMwHOzY7GOXK4PF4fP4BSE-pFKEb+m6VxemEDRj11HcJimYU8z6IQZAXAcayQYcG1HNQWynGc5wgBciUA3VC1-NYYmBFl0kyDl8kKEpyiqGo6gaJBbzab91G6Q1+GPQZhnvMY7hmG1xUWc0GGifZDmOU5zkuHI2N+PdWAPXMNAAOVdFUmXPOsrzHFslU0viLCsJ8kHIeQTjwbp7FfKoDNOSp5OIgFenUt1zGBEC1I005IMFaC-1gtzNIQnskOkFDchXdDxyQLDZ3nRd7PMIjnJFMiklZSiwByaiilKCpwUYmR4QRNiDVcnymVNIz-MBGQisqUTAQko4TjOC4rj8kJvV9ZBRnbeQJOTaI2jk5qrRKxFwzoX4aCjaA4EQJAAHUIA4CsTH1ChTiwWMkETPA8GoVEDHc6ExDFCUpVCMxzJOJB7iMHsLOgYFbUlaUxCOkg5C+jgFhaSh1QJaUWO8fQoHkZUNmlVQIHYD13LY+7kFU-hDuOpxmvinC8ieogXpOKBoXh9hG10ZqURAMoZFx+cCaJ6A8SqwtoRBABrK7FjJWsFBxPQqaQMRabi6cEtwxnXpJoTrrZ0EIo+hZeYvIEFMYEh-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-GAKzgwGCAAvRowAOZ8AAO48F-oAPg3ADsu4AWAJABCZIAeD-HLJPYj0DGR1hCpN4sEqCSB0nMUyTk4AzVUmWKiCmYwrAsl4FyQEvq08BKKggG4U4eJ+AHSOi4ixqSL6WPTpnQBQRQhAA)

Answer (score 4):

You may be looking for combining [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) with the [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```
function notUndef<T>(obj: T): obj is Exclude<T, undefined> {
    return obj !== void(0);
}
```