# What is the purpose of `string & {}`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I was trying to typehint the `gridTemplateColumns` css property, and in a dependency of React called csstype I found the following property definition:

```
  gridTemplateColumns?: Property.GridTemplateColumns<TLength> | undefined;
```

This is a property of the following interface, where `TLength` and `TTime` are declared.

```
export interface StandardLonghandProperties<TLength = (string & {}) | 0, TTime = string & {}> {
```

I don't understand what `string & {}` is trying to accomplish. How is it different than just a regular `string`?

Comment: I would normally expect to see that in the face of a union with string literals so as not to absorb them for IntelliSense/documentation purposes, as mentioned in [ms/TS#29729](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729).  (e.g., `(string & {}) | "x")` is equivalent to `string` in terms of what values it accepts, but IntelliSense will prompt you with `"x"`) But `0` is a number literal so I also don't see why it's not just `string` in those particular examples.

Comment: So, csstype's typescript declarations are generated and according to [frenic/csstype#74](//github.com/frenic/csstype/pull/74) they just blanket replaced `string` and `number` with `(string & {})` or `(number & {})` to allow autocomplete/autosuggest to work as described in ms/TS#29729.  The particular example you show has no purpose, but in other cases it .  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, this is pretty much the extent of my question and your answer is much appreciated. I suppose you might mention what could be done with the type parameter. I guess its so you can specify other defaults. I think perhaps that `0` is there because it is valid as a length without a unit unlike other numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the so-called empty object type `{}` only excludes `null` and `undefined` (see [How to undestand relations between types any, unknown, {} and between them and other types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59135229/2887218)), the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `string & {}` is equivalent to `string` in terms of what values it accepts.  So for most purposes there is no difference between `string` and `string & {}` and thus no reason to use the more complicated type.

But even though `string & {}` might be considered the same as `string`, the compiler does not eagerly reduce the former to the latter, the way it does for, say, `string & unknown` (where [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown) is absorbed by the intersection with `string`), or the way it does for [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) like `string | "x"` (where the string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"x"` is absorbed by the union with `string`).

So one use of `string & {}` is to prevent some of these eager reductions for IntelliSense autosuggest/autocomplete and documentation purposes.  The type `(string & {}) | "x"` allows the same values as `string`, but still has enough "memory" of the `"x"` type for it to be suggested by an IntelliSense-enabled IDE.  This technique is mentioned in [microsoft/TypeScript#29729](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729) as a workaround for the lack of native support for autocompletion of string literal unions with `string`.

---

Still, in the case of `(string & {}) | 0` and `string & {}` as shown in the [definition for the `StandardLonghandProperties` interface in frenic/csstype](https://github.com/frenic/csstype/blob/7a4673d16e2205b9ecea77b5414ba5c9ecd0f660/index.d.ts#L11), it seems unmotivated.  There's no difference in the IntelliSense you'd be prompted with for `(string & {}) | 0` and just `string | 0` (since `0` is a numeric literal it doesn't get absorbed in the union), and there's definitely no difference in the IntelliSense prompting for `string & {}` and just `string`, since there are no literals to suggest at all.

So, why is it like that?  If you look at the [frenic/csstype#73](https://github.com/frenic/csstype/issues/73) issue, it seems that there are a bunch of places that *do* use a union of string literals with `string`, where IntelliSense suffered.  Apparently frenic/csstype has its its own build system to *generate* the TypeScript declaration file.  So the fix in [frenic/csstype#74](https://github.com/frenic/csstype/pull/74) was to just change the generation code so that instead of just `string` and `number` types, it would generate `(string & {})` and `(number & {})`.

That means there really isn't much of a reason for `string & {}` in the code you're looking at. If the maintainers of frenic/csstype wanted to, they could change the code so that `string` and `number` are left alone in places where they are not part of a union with literals of the same base type.  That is, they could make sure that `& {}` only shows up in places where it improves IntelliSense suggestions.

But that would take more work.  And while such a change might reduce the sort of confusion that prompted this question, it's not like the current code has a *bug*.  Instead, it's a (mostly) harmless side-effect.