# Generic enum typeguard

Tags: typescript, enums

I want to write a generic type guard for enums but this doesn't work so far in TS 5.0.4

```js
function isEnumValue<T>(enumType: T, value: unknown): value is T[keyof T] {
  return Object.values(enumType).includes(value as T[keyof T]);
}
//-----------------------^--------------------------
//             No overload matches this call

enum Sort {
  A,
  B
}
function isSort(value: unknown): value is Sort {
  return isEnumValue(Sort, value);
}

enum Order {
  ASC,
  DESC
}
function isOrder(value: unknown): value is Order {
  return isEnumValue(Order, value);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgUTCAtgNQIYA2IApgDwAqAfABTGZbkCeADsQFyLkA0iAboSQ7gA1mDgB3MAEoO-IsWQpOAbWHFGcYJwC6iAN4AoRIgBOxKCBNIA8gCMAVsWgA6OSRS16TVlOcxIRAAmxB5uCnhK5KrqmjpSANwGAL4GBnTYiADKcCZQ%20kaIAIJcBQBCyQagkLAIitm51GFCYKIS0rICCqhZOXmGxmYWVooY2Pjy1PVQPGEJFWn0iNYmwSb5xoWZAMIlxgAiaNsVVdDwSKjLq42dza2SMnydiksrxGv9puaW5%20j04yTUS5vGadOZJIA)

Maybe I can have a hint ? ;)

Comment: TS's typings for `Object.values()` requires the argument to be non-nullable, so you just need to constrain `T` to something non-nullable like `{}` as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WYQZxW).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Also this implementation is incorrect as `Sort = {
  "0": "A",
  "1": "B",
  "A": 0,
  "B": 1
} `. Correct one is `typeof enumType[value] === 'string'`

Comment: It fully answers my request @jcalz but considering @Dimava answer maybe I should fix my implementation to handle the case where there is no default values for my enum keys ? 
In my case, I had default values like `Sort = { A = 'a', B = 'b' }` but as stated in the question I wanted to write a generic enum typeguard ;D

Comment: Are you suggesting that your whole function is just an example and we could replace it, and you're not trying to resolve the error you mentioned?  Hmm, well you could filter out the reverse mapping by ignoring numericlike keys, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w29z4W).  Does that meet your needs?

Comment: I only wanted to check if `Sort.A` `"a"` are valid enum values so I think your first solution works well in my case with no edge cases, wdty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you just want to resolve the "no overload matches this call" error and that the implementation of the function works as you intend at runtime... even though numeric enums have [reverse mappings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings) where `Object.values(enumType).includes(value)` will give a false positive when `value` is one of the enum *keys*.  There are ways to work around that but I'm considering this out of scope here.

---

The problem you're running into is that your [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` is not [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), and therefore could be any type at all, including those with [`null` or `undefined`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#null-and-undefined) in their domain.  And so the `enumType` parameter can be of such a type.

But the [TypeScript library typings](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/8fae437660ba89353fc7104beae8c6856528e5b6/src/lib/es2017.object.d.ts#L2-L12) for [the `Object.values()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) are like

```
interface ObjectConstructor {      
  values<T>(o: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>): T[];
  values(o: {}): any[];
}
```

where the parameter must at least be assignable to the type `{}`, which allows just about anything *except* for `null` and `undefined`.  See [How to undestand relations between types any, unknown, {} and between them and other types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59135229/2887218) for more information.

So neither of the two call signatures for `Object.values()` shown above is appropriate.  `T` is certainly not constrained to `{[s: string]: unknown} | ArrayLike<unknown>}` as needed for the first call signature, and it is not constrained to `{}` as needed for the second call signature.

In other words: since nothing stops someone from calling

```
isEnumValue(null, "a");
```

the compiler doesn't want to let you pass `enumType` into `Object.values()`

---

The fix for this is therefore to constrain `T` to be the non-nullable `{}` type:

```
function isEnumValue<T extends {}>(enumType: T, value: unknown): value is T[keyof T] {
  return Object.values(enumType).includes(value as T[keyof T]); // okay
}
```

This works because now `isEnumValue()` cannot be called with a possibly-nullish `enumType` argument.  If you call `isEnumValue(null, "a")` you'll get a compiler error at the call site:

```
isEnumValue(null, "a"); // error
// Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}'.
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgUTCAtgNQIYA2IApgDwAqixAHlMWACYqIDeAvgHwAU925AngAdiALkTkANIgBuhEmPABrMHADuYAJRjZRYsmbkA2ouL84wcQF1WAKESIATsSggHSAPIAjAFbFoAOh0SFB5MLAFhDX8YSCIGYhCgvTwDY1NzKw0Abhs2GxtUDGx8XS5MAgIpACI8KuzEAHoGqgcHOAcbJsQAQQcAc2x6KEQMqCE9AHJyggn9RBVhlJQYPrA8TwI9KDhEQTwHPCxnYgcRizHhRAn2Cf983ixEAGV24ZY7HokPgCFcm1BILAEPoXg4oFwkgowMo1JptHI9Khnq9bPYnC43PoirgEVxQVApElsn8bA9EO4HPFTu97N0ngBhL72AAiaAZfwB0HgSFQFKpEIRUJh6i0MgRcz5J1Rjmcrh56DCJRIXElDkJCOJbCAA)

Comment: That's a great explanation thanks. By the way in common tslint rules we are urge to not use that kind of constraint i.e. `Don't use `{}` as a type. `{}` actually means "any non-nullish value"....`
Do you suggest disabling the rule or is there another solution?

Comment: You can possibly write `extends object` instead of `extends {}`.  It really depends on what kind of constraint you want to see.  You could also put `extends Record<keyof T, string | umber>` to makes sure that it only accepts things with string/number property values.  Personally though if the intent is "accept anything non-nullish" than `extends {}` is exactly what you want, and that eslint ban-types rule is probably not useful there.