# Typescript, Infer values that are not null from string identifier

Tags: typescript

Say I have a dynamic object with keys and values. The keys can be of any type including `null` and `undefined`.

Now say I have a function which takes an array of string paths to values in said object and returns `true` if all of them exist (not `null` or `undefined`).

How can I get typescript to infer this information so that I do not need to use `!` operator:

```js
interface Foo {
  a?: { i?: number; ii?: number },
  b?: string;
  c?: {}
}
var object: Foo = {
    a: {
        i: undefined,
        ii: 1
    },
    b: undefined,
    c: {}
}

if (exists(object, ["a.ii", "c"])) // returns true if `object.a.ii` and `object.c` is not `null` or `undefined`
{
    // get typescript to infer that `object.a.ii` is not `null` or `undefined`
    // so that I can ommit `!` operator
    let value: number = object.a.ii!;
}
```

I know you can achieve this like so:

```js
function exists<T>(object: T | null | undefined): object is T
{
    return object !== null && object !== undefined;
}

if (exists(object.a.ii) && exists(object.c))
{
    let value: number = object.a.ii; // works fine without '!' operator
}
```

but I want to know if its possible using the string paths.

EDIT: Added type to example

Comment: ① A [mre] where you define your types would be helpful so that others don't have to spend any time resolving `SomeTypeAllowingNullAndUndefinedProperties` themselves and possibly produce a solution that doesn't actually work for your use case. ② Do you really intend for `exists` not to take `object` as an argument?  If so, that's probably not going to work.  If not, then could you [edit] to fix it?

Comment: ③ Assuming you fix those first two, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mpxzxm) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz your example is exactly what I wanted thank you! I do intend to not pass in object but I can get around it by setting it as a default parameter (I think), so it should work fine.

Comment: No, you can't do that.  Type guard functions only narrow the arguments passed in.  (Try it, you'll see it doesn't work.)  How should I proceed then?  Just say "this is impossible"?  Or can we pass in the argument?  (And, either way, could you please [edit] to define your type?)

Comment: @jcalz We can pass in the argument, its fine. Thanks for your help! I've also done the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want the `exists(obj, paths)` function to be a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).  If `obj` is of generic type `T` and `paths` is of generic type `K[]`, then we want a `true` return value to narrow `obj` to subtype of `T` known to have non-[nullish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Nullish) properties at the paths represented by `K`.

That means we need to write a "nested" version of [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) that treats `K` as a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of dotted paths instead of a union of plain keys.  Let's call it `NestedRecord<K, V>`.  We'd want it to act like this:

```
type Example = NestedRecord<
  "z.y.x" | "z.w.v" | "u.t" | "u.t.s" | "r.q" | "p",
  Date
>;
/* type Example = {
  z: {
    y: { x: Date; };
    w: { v: Date; };
  };
  u: { t: Date & { s: Date; }; };
  r: { q: Date; };
  p: Date;
}*/
```

And since non-nullish values correspond exactly to the "empty object type" `{}` (see [How to undestand relations between types any, unknown, {} and between them and other types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59135229/2887218) ), we'll want the call signature of `exists()` to look like:

```
declare function exists<T extends object, K extends string>(
  obj: T, paths: K[]
): obj is T & NestedRecord<K, {}>;
```

So now we have to define `NestedRecord<K, V>`.

---

Here's one way to do it:

```
type NestedRecord<K extends string, V> = [K] extends [never] ? unknown : {
  [P in (K extends `${infer K0}.${string}` ? K0 : K)]:
  (P extends K ? V : unknown) &
  NestedRecord<K extends `${P}.${infer KR}` ? KR : never, V>
}
```

This is using [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) as well as [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to parse the keys in `K`.  The keys of `NestedRecord<K, V>` should just be the parts of `K` before the first dots, or any parts of `K` without dots.  And the values of `NestedRecord<K, V>` should be `V` for any `K` without dots, [intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with `NestedRecord<K, V>` for the parts of `K` after the first dots that start with the current key.

Oh, and `NestedRecord<never, V>` should be `unknown` instead of `{}`, just so that we don't have a lot of annoying intersections with `{}` in the end type.

You can verify that this definition behaves as desired for `Example` above.

---

Finally we need to implement `exists()`.  Here's one way to do that, maybe:

```
function exists<T extends object, K extends string>(
  obj: T, paths: K[]
): obj is T & NestedRecord<K, {}> {
  return paths.every(p => p.split(".").reduce((a, k) => (a ?? a[k]), obj) != null);
}
```

I'm using the [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) array methods to verify that `object` has a non-nullish value at every path in `paths`.

---

Let's try it on your example `object`:

```
object;
// ^? var object: Foo
if (exists(object, ["a.ii", "c"])) {
  object;
  // ^? var object: Foo & { a: { ii: {}; }; c: {}; }
  let value = object.a.ii;
  // ^? let value: number
  console.log(value); // 1
}
```

Looks good.  Inside the guarded code block, `object` has been narrowed from `Foo` to `Foo & { a: { ii: {}; }; c: {}; }`, which means that when we drill into `object.a.ii` the type is `(number | undefined) & {}`, which is just `number`, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQDED2nUG9iqoID8AXHqiGamAK4C2ARrANyVXl1OyoC+ANAVSNqAZwgxwAcxZCk1XL2BLgANwQxUmRgCsoSCOSw4AvHiEJy+QoRDlaYACZQ44KI8E325AIxCBQoz2Ti5uHnJWSirAEACeAA5oAHJQ4u4ASvqYMI4APADSqFAAHtBOoqjikmBS-KgAagB8qGYA2vkAukWlUOWorWBQqrBdxKgOANZgmADuYKhWQq0ACpTzABSFJWWOFQAGACS44HA8+QAMvAB0R1XSvHuoYxcLqPkAlB2kQuur2727N5PBqvSbTObvVAAMiEKTSjkySGyeS2PT6h1wy2uRxOZ3SD2B+XSr0GwxgdSaymAMQSaAAosUEPR4gAbNBmOHQBFZHK5IQAIgAXldYldivzUAAfVBCq4zK6qCXS-m0K4QJUy1UQK6iDX8mBXACOevi-M8qAAIghoMBGrIAPQAKlQcUSqAZTNZ7PMhEFiy8sSsqGK5Ct0DYvFkXhmQdUoetUAjUb4ydoQcMloT0Ioonj4ZTKaEMCDhrzicLhHiZdkvEd9up1LgDgMIEw8xKIHEolyABVujsKto9AY6qiB5UJNJGushEPyD26vFrQALXNvVodYDvchDygVPtQ1CcjI8lF1RTNayoGBQCC0GDzJcQVdXIawWLreItZrxHWskAQOs-JXPy7xXDeji0Cg6zrAgdQTJCJjNLBTxjAgrQTB07x1EOkIAIRmHQLIsu8NYNkO+gQA69qoAAemM6iaBRBhGNgoBwKg6wdl26zMRAdStPyCBXCAIBmjKSD8lhkJXnxyb2jR9GoIxWi6JRrE4IeuBEEGomREmqBIPpfBCGyEDKQgLK0N6fFXMJonyYpYxmRZVlQJwDDMDAchtqImBslcLKYFI6zqG5pGoApqB+LwQA)