# How to define a type when you just know one key in the object

Tags: typescript

I am trying to define a type for an object

Let's say the object is something like this

```
{
  a: 123,
  b: "hello",
  c: {
       d:"world"
     }
}
```

And I don't know the keys that will be present in the object.

So I would define its type as `Record<string, any>`

But how do I define the type if I know just one key in the object and the others are still unknown?

In the example above let's say I know the type of `c`. So its `c:{d: string}` but I still don't know the type of other so I would still want the other to be `Record<string, any>`

Comment: Sounds like you're just looking for an *index signature* as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WvxZAN). Does that meet your needs? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks. that is exactly what i was looking for. I tried to just make it work with Record type but this solution works great too. Thanks. Happy to accept the answer if you post it

Comment: Note that `Record<string, unknown>` evaluates to `{[k: string]: unknown}`, so it does "work with" that.  You could have written `{c:{d:string}} & Record<string, unknown>` too, but single interface types are nicer to work with than intersections of object types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object types with known property keys can also have [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) for classes of property keys like `string`, as long as the property types at known keys are compatible with the property type for the index signature.  In your case it would look like this:

```
interface Foo {
  c: { d: string };
  [k: string]: unknown; 
}
```

That says: a `Foo` has a `c` property of type `{d: string}`, and for any key `k` of type `string`, the property at that key should be of [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type).  All types, including `{d: string}`, are assignable to `unknown`, so this is a valid definition, and your assignment works:

```
const obj: Foo = {
  a: 123,
  b: "hello",
  c: {
    d: "world"
  }
}; // okay
```

---

Notes:

- you could use [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) instead of `unknown` if you want, as long as you're aware of their behaviors; see [How to undestand relations between types any, unknown, {} and between them and other types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59135229/2887218) for more information.
- you could use [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) like `Record<string, unknown>` instead of `{[k: string]: unknown}`, since the former just evaluates to the latter. Personally I would use the index signature directly rather than hide it behind `Record`.  See [What is the Record type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51936369/2887218) for more information.
- If you do use `Record`, there's no way to add the known keys directly to it.  Instead you'd need to use an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) like `{c: {d: string}} & Record<string, unknown>}`.  Intersections of object types are similar to single combined object type, but [there are differences](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#interfaces-vs-intersections).  I would use a single type instead of intersections where possible, but this is just personal preference.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIIBcOyAJiQM5hSgDmyAvgNz7IDaA1lTfQLokAriE4h0AdxCtGuXAnQhqydACMAViQxYAvDjZwSARgBMAZgA0bFSQBEACwgAbR+huWCxPQQIVkN8ehQjmQ2bDIyuCBwALYQlAAOiCgAkuDQlBAIYF7IYACe8ShayLp43oQk2OQ8tCAMLGHIAGTIAEqZgWQAPNS1dObIwqISIAB8rGzyitmqGmiYJTkEBsgmFmwE1n4Ozq7u3p5l5dV+AUEhG0xhsriMQA)