# Why do we use 'as keyof'?

Tags: typescript, keyof

```
    const isTrue = <T>(arg: T): { arg: T; is: boolean } => {
  if (Array.isArray(arg) && !arg.length) {
    return { arg, is: false };
  }
  if (isObject(arg) && !Object.keys(arg as keyof T).length) {
    return { arg, is: false };
  }
  return { arg, is: !!arg };
};
```

In this code, why do we use arg as keyof T? We checked it is an object with the statement 'isObject(arg)' then it should be an object. But *as keyof T* means that arg's type will be the keys of the object. So how can *arg* still act like an object despite we used 'as keyof T'?

I added isObject function here:

```
const isObject = <T>(par: T): boolean => {
  return typeof par === "object" && !Array.isArray(par) && par !== null;
};
```

Comment: The usage of `as keyof T` is incorrect. The correct way would be to write as follows: `(Object.keys(arg) as (keyof T)[]).length`

Comment: @wonderflame this time it gives an error.

Comment: Which error? If it is `string[]` is not assignable to `(keyof T)[]` then it is expected

Comment: red squiggly line under the 'arg' and when I mouse over it says 'No overload matches this cal...'

Comment: Well it depends on what `isObject` is doing

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that others can paste into their own IDEs to see what you're seeing.  Right now there are not enough debugging details since `isObject()` hasn't been declared and apparently this is the vital piece of your problem.  Certainly `arg as keyof T` is nonsense, but whatever issue you're talking about now is either unrelated or irreproducible.  You can write `arg as object` and it would make more sense, but this just brings up the question about what `isObject` is doing if not narrowing `arg` from `T` to `T & object`.

Comment: I added isObject function. And by the way, when I change 'as keyof t' to 'as object', it worked. Actually I have seen this code block in a tutorial and It didn't make sense to me as well, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which tutorial that code came from, but you are right to be confused; given `arg` of type `T`, it is almost certainly meaningless to later [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that `arg` is of type [`keyof T`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator), especially if you've already checked that `arg` is an `object` and not a `string` or `symbol`.  It's a fun exercise to try to devise situations in which `T & keyof T` is non-empty, like the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"length"`.  But this is not the case here, and even if it were, it's a bizarre thing to do.

Again, the assertion `arg as keyof T` isn't true.

---

If you don't assert then the compiler complains because `arg` isn't known to be something that `Object.keys()` accepts.  If you look at [the most permissive call signature for `Object.keys()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/d495200a4ab8d9cdf9a65e6669da4d611252751a/src/lib/es2015.core.d.ts#L305), it is

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
  keys(o: {}): string[];
}
```

The parameter is `{}`, the so-called "empty object type", and while it usually refers to objects, it also is applicable to even non-object values that can be indexed into (e.g., `string` is allowed because you can index into them with keys like `"toUpperCase"` and `"length"`).  In other words, the only values that are *not* assignable to `{}` are [`null` and `undefined`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#null-and-undefined).  (See
[How to undestand relations between types any, unknown, {} and between them and other types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59135229/2887218))

Since the `isObject()` function you presented does not [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) its input (it returns `boolean` as opposed to a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates); another indication that the tutorial might be problematic), then the compiler has no idea that `arg` will be an object.  And thus if you call `Object.keys(arg)` directly, the compiler will complain because `arg` is of type `T` which *might* allow `null` or `undefined`:

```
Object.keys(arg); // error!
// -------> ~~~
// Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}'.
```

The mistaken assertion `arg as keyof T` suppresses that error because `keyof T` is some subtype of `string | number | symbol`, each of which is non-nullish.

The only thing `as keyof T` does for you is that it narrows `arg` to something known to be non-nullish.  So it suppresses the error, but in a very strange way.  It would work just as well to say `Object.keys(arg as Date)` or `Object.keys(arg as Math)` or `Object.keys(arg as "whoopsieDoodle")`.  And then you'd be asking similar questions about why `Math` is relevant.  It isn't.

---

A *reasonable* thing to do here would be to assert that `arg` is [the `object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type), which is presumably what `isObject()` is meant to do:

```
Object.keys(arg as object) // okay
```

Even more reasonable would be if `isObject()` were a type guarding function as presumably is intended:

```
const isObject = (par: any): par is object => {
  return typeof par === "object" && par !== null;
};

const isTrue = <T,>(arg: T): { arg: T; is: boolean } => {
  if (Array.isArray(arg) && !arg.length) {
    return { arg, is: false };
  }
  if (isObject(arg) && !Object.keys(arg).length) { // okay
    return { arg, is: false };
  }
  return { arg, is: !!arg };
};
```

But this is essentially a digression from the question as asked.

---

To reiterate:

Q: Why do we use `arg as keyof T`?

A: Most likely because we are confused and used the first thing we found that suppressed a compiler error.  We should really have used `arg as object` or some other approach entirely.  We should probably edit our tutorial, now that we think about it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4Ch8kl4B7YKAFyQyhQCMArCeagXiQB4AVAGgD4AFHDQAuJNwCU4+qVIAbCCGBI2-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-gCpsWWfCNkgAPSjpAAWmnM9nc-nc-USAAfquEWOJ-4sHpIMBqBCbcgAOTcI+tZKkajAqDYUD0RRISikazRcC6CBoJAH0zH3BZI-BOuFY7AyGJtEgtY4kG+LXMBJLVpi5KUtB5zqvSlJMjCLJssGFBcjyfLVIKLwimKhCStAcCIEgABiGAAB6KsqqqELh9Kts6kZ6l6hrtKaKhprBVpGD+drRLYjrdm4Mx+LmIQ5hEXoFr6HD+hk1JoaG4ZlLqlQxnU8E1BILSIUmSgpr0ZYZlmckenJ+adnMzJwlZWhwVWWBgVidZUgMBJaM2dx0N2DkyVqPZgv2LyNCCTouFCzmlumbnCYZXkQdi9bXP5iKpR56XeBS0UoTSbFXtFmEljhJAcvh8i8gKwqivg4oUdK1F0fRACSwWcWqZWat2Oo8Y0wDGEaNi0F+Q2CZayIibaVj2kkjhST64mJKpqTqZcpU1RqRQlDpUaArxhkJqZHTmd0lnJYF2bjPZHYyU5WEucluXzWlNaZb5MEDIFHEuKF7zhb2-z5oO71AXloE-T50GNnNxL5WShXIYGe10uVjJIPYiXVXSdUNURTVikAA)