# Argument of type 'T & {}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Exclude<T, null>'.ts(2345) (parameter) rawValue: T & {}

Tags: typescript

For some reason, my `T` generic is becoming `T & {}` (T and/combined/intersected with empty object)

```
export const handleNull = <
  T extends string | number | null,
>(
  rawValue: T,
  {
    format,
  }: {
    format: (
      value: Exclude<T, null>,
    ) => string
  },
) => {
  if (rawValue === null) {
    return ''
  }

  return format(rawValue)
  //            ^^^^^^^^
  // Argument of type 'T & {}' is not assignable to
  // parameter of type 'Exclude<T, null>'. ts(2345)
  //   (parameter) rawValue: T & {}`
}
```

`Argument of type 'T & {}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Exclude<T, null>'.ts(2345) (parameter) rawValue: T & {}`

How can I solve this without a simple assertion?

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wBYENkBMA2wAcgK775wC8cAPAFBxwAqcoMweqc6UAlsgHM4AHzjISAWwBGwKCLFl8AGjoA+ABQM4ULAHcAalnwlgALmYrGAby2MAZtAlYYluAF9zNxvcfPzm728ANyMTcwBREARjXGAaJiUFclVXRgBKKlVuGD5BLTcVDMosrzheOzh1HQNQ4CpKanFyDNLGKGAYEihkOAByXvy6LXbO7rgHKCcYKr1DY2A0ujcgA)

[image: TypeScript playground preview]

As a bonus, why is my type generic being intersected with empty object type `{}` and getting `& {}` added onto the end of it?

Comment: Can you change `Exclude<T, null>` to `NonNullable<T>`? The former is no longer how non-nullability is expressed in the type system, and it's a generic conditional type, which is harder for the compiler to reason about that `NonNullable` which is an intersection.

Comment: It seems that using NonNullable fixes the downstream type error! :) I did have one question - `NonNullable` is defined as `/** Exclude null and undefined from T */ type NonNullable<T> = T & {};`. Question was, does this mean my value passed back to `format` could also be undefined according to the type system? And for a given T of `number | null`, the answer is NO, `NonNullable` will not incidentally introduce `undefined` into the union. Thanks @jcalz!

Comment: @jcalz is there any situation in which `Exclude<Foo, null>` would be preferred over `NonNullable<Foo>`?

Comment: Maybe? It's hard to get a handle on what "any situation" might encompass. Generally speaking, `{} | null | undefined` is now similar enough to `unknown` that `Exclude<T, null>` can be one-for-one replaced with `T & ({} | undefined)`, which could just be `T & {}` if `T` can't include `undefined` to start with.  Anyway I'll write an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: Why is there now a "bonus" here? Is the scope of the question changing? I really prefer for questions to stabilize before answering them.

Comment: Sorry, was just curious about that. I can remove it from this one

Comment: Happy to award you the answer btw, since you quickly helped me get past the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant behavior in TypeScript here is documented at [microsoft/TypeScript#49119](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/49119), which was released [with TypeScript 4.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-8.html#improved-intersection-reduction-union-compatibility-and-narrowing).

---

TypeScript considers all types to be assignable to the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `{} | null | undefined`.  That is, it's a "synonym" of [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type).  See [How to undestand relations between types any, unknown, {} and between them and other types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59135229/2887218;) the type `{}` corresponds to any non-[nullish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Nullish) type (even primitives), so `{} | null | undefined` is basically "everything".

By [intersecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) a type with some sub-union of `{} | null | undefined`, you can filter the type to include just those pieces that match.  So if you have a type `X` and want to say "just those `X` types which are non-nullish", you can write `X & {}`.  Indeed this is now the definition of [the `NonNullable<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype).

TypeScript is, especially since 4.8, more able to analyze [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) intersections than it is able to analyze generic [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).  Since [the `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) is implemented as a conditional type, then `Exclude<T, null | undefined>` is much harder for the compiler to reason about than the conceptually identical `NonNullable<T>`.

Thus, you will have better results if you replace `Exclude<T, null | undefined>` with `NonNullable<T>`.

Note that if `T` cannot possibly be `undefined` (say by being [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a type which doesn't allow it like `string | number | null`), then `T & {}` has the same effect as `T & ({} | undefined)`.  Meaning that in this case, `Exclude<T, null>` is conceptually equivalent to `Exclude<T, null | undefined>`, and therefore `NonNullable<T>`.

That gives us:

```
export const handleNull = <T extends string | number | null>(
  rawValue: T,
  { format }: { format: (value: NonNullable<T>) => string }
) => {
  if (rawValue === null) { return '' }
  return format(rawValue); // okay
}
```

And the problem goes away.  This relies on the fact that the check `rawValue === null` also narrows the type of `rawValue` from `T` to `T & {}`.  This happens as described in microsoft/TypeScript#49119:

> - In control flow analysis of equality comparisons with `null` or `undefined`, generic types are intersected with `{}`, `{} | null`, or `{} | undefined` in the false branch.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wBYENkBMA2wAcgK775wC8cAPACpygzB6pzpQCWyA5nAD5xkJALYAjYFAFCy+AHwAKAFBw4ULAHcAalnwlgALjh0ANCrgBvOADNoIrPAC+Rq7aj2YRhQDdd+o0QopORYYoT0cgCUVHLsMFy8cI5K0ZSxFuac1nAK6tp+wFSU1MLk0VZQwDAkUMhwAOT1SeaV1bU2dg65mjp6wJEA3HAA9MNwEADWWACeSslKQA)

Answer (score 1):

A common solution to this issue is to move `| null` out of the generics and onto the parameter type, thus avoiding the need to use `Exclude`. For example:

```js
export const handleNull = <T extends string | number>(
  rawValue: T | null,
  format: (value: T) => string
) => {
  if (rawValue === null) {
    return ''
  }
  return format(rawValue)
}
```